# How to extract Excel PivotCache into Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

First time posting here, I apologize if this question has been asked before - I can't find anything that applies.

Is there a way to read the underlying data from an Excel PivotTable into a Pandas Data Frame?  For several years I've had an Excel Auto_Open macro that downloads several Excel files and double clicks on the "Grand Total" row in order to extract all of the data, which ultimate gets imported into a database.  This is done because the owners of the source data refuse to grant access to the database itself.

This macro has never been the ideal scenario and we need to move it to a better method soon.  I have extensive SQL knowledge but have only recently begun to learn Python.

I have been able to read worksheets using OpenPyXl, but these files do not contain the source data on a separate worksheet by default - the pivotcache must be extracted to a new sheet first.  What I would like to do, if possible, is read from the Excel PivotCache into a Pandas Data Frame and either save that output as a CSV or load it directly into our database.  It seems that this is not capable with OpenPyXl and that I'll probably need to use win32com.client.

Does anybody have any experience with this, and know if it's even possible?  Any pointers for where I might get started?  I've tried several items from the Excel Object model (PivotCache, GetData, etc etc) but either I don't know how to use them or they don't return what I need.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: so the macro reads a datasource via http/rest and only outputs a single row for your database? or is the data hidden in a sheet? try `xl=pd.ExcelFile(file)` and then do `print(xl.sheet_names)` is the data on one of those tabs?

Comment: The macro itself downloads zip files, unzips them, opens the Excel files contained therein, doubleclicks the pivot table to produce a data sheet, then saves the file.  Said data sheet is then imported into SQL Server.  The data sheet itself does not exist by default, it's embedded within the pivot table and it must be extracted first.  Its identical to creating a pivot table from a data sheet, then deleting the data sheet before saving.  The data itself can still be extracted by doubleclicking the pivot table to extract the pivot cache.  It's not a hidden sheet issue.  Several thousand rows.

Comment: I'm not familair with PivotCache but if you can do `df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='pivot_data')` then you process your data and output to csv with `df.to_csv`

Comment: This is the core of my question.  The pivot table data does not exist on a sheet initially, it has to be created by double clicking the pivot table (which i don't know how to do in Python, only in Excel VBA, which is what I'm trying to avoid).  I'm trying to figure out if i can read directly from the pivot cache (which is what double clicking does) from within Python without involving any excel VBA or manual action.

Comment: I think the cache data is stored as XML inside the xlsx file (assuming you're working with that format) - you could unzip the workbook and extract from there...

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how i could extract that info?  The files are already being unzipped, but I've never extracted the cache data in such a way.  I've had to process XML before, so after I have it I won't have any issues.  Just how do I get it like that in the first place?  Have you done it before or have any websites to start with for info?

Comment: Thank you, Tim, I understand what you mean now.  XLSX files can be explored.  When I arrive at a solution I will be sure to post it.

Comment: Did you end up solving your question? I'm currently facing a similar issue...

Comment: I did not as conditions at my company changed shortly after asking and it is no longer a priority for the time being (the impact to my job would be minimal in comparison).

Comment: I did discover what I believe to be the XML file(s) that house the pivot cache data in the Excel binary, however.  The downside is that it appears to be formatted as one entire line, so loading it in Notepad++ or the like still doesn't show line breaks.  Its makes the XML very avoidant to being examined.  There might be a tool somewhere that will do that for you, but that is where I left off and would have been my next task to explore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is very late, but I came up with it while struggling with the same issue, and some of the comments above helped me nail it.

In essence, the steps one can take to solve this with `openpyxl` are:

1. Use `openpyxl` to get the `openpyxl.pivot.table.TableDefinition` object from the desired pivot table (let's call it `my_pivot_table`)
2. Get cached fields and their values from `my_pivot_table.cache.cacheFields`
3. Get rows data as a `dict` in two sub-steps:

   - 3.1) Get all cached rows and their values from `my_pivot_table.cache.records.r`. Cache fields in these records are stored as indexes from `my_pivot_table.cache.cacheFields`
   - 3.2) Replace cache fields from each record by their actual values, by "joining" `cache.records.r` and `cache.cacheFields`
4. Convert `dict` with rows into a `pandas` DataFrame

Below you will find a copy of the code that implements such solution. Since the structure of these Excel objects are somewhat complex, the code will probably look very cryptic (sorry about that). To address this, I'm adding further below minimal examples of the main objects being manipulated, so people can get a better sense of what is going on, what are the objects being returned, etc.

This was the simplest approach I could find to achieve this. I hope it is still useful for someone, albeit some tweaking may be needed for individual cases.

### "Bare" code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.pivot.fields import Missing

file_path = 'path/to/your/file.xlsx'

workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
worksheet = workbook['Plan1']

# Name of desired pivot table (the same name that appears within Excel)
pivot_name = 'Tabela dinâmica1'

# Extract the pivot table object from the worksheet
pivot_table = [p for p in worksheet._pivots if p.name == pivot_name][0]

# Extract a dict of all cache fields and their respective values
fields_map = {}
for field in pivot_table.cache.cacheFields:
    if field.sharedItems.count > 0:
        fields_map[field.name] = [f.v for f in field.sharedItems._fields]

# Extract all rows from cache records. Each row is initially parsed as a dict
column_names = [field.name for field in pivot_table.cache.cacheFields]
rows = []
for record in pivot_table.cache.records.r:
    # If some field in the record in missing, we replace it by NaN
    record_values = [
        field.v if not isinstance(field, Missing) else np.nan for field in record._fields
    ]

    row_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(column_names, record_values)}

    # Shared fields are mapped as an Index, so we replace the field index by its value
    for key in fields_map:
        row_dict[key] = fields_map[key][row_dict[key]]

    rows.append(row_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)
```

Results:

```
>>> df.head(2)

            FUEL    YEAR   REGION     STATE  UNIT       Jan       Feb  (...)
0  GASOLINE (m3)  2000.0        S     TEXAS    m3  9563.263  9563.263  (...)
1  GASOLINE (m3)  2000.0       NE  NEW YORK    m3  3065.758  9563.263  (...)
```

### Some of the objects details

#### Object `pivot_table`

This is an object of type `openpyxl.pivot.table.TableDefinition`. It is quite complex. A small glimpse of it:

```
<openpyxl.pivot.table.TableDefinition object>
Parameters:
name='Tabela dinâmica1', cacheId=36, dataOnRows=True, dataPosition=None, (A LOT OF OMITTED STUFF...)
Parameters:
ref='B52:W66', firstHeaderRow=1, firstDataRow=2, firstDataCol=1, rowPageCount=2, colPageCount=1, pivotFields=[<openpyxl.pivot.table.PivotField object>
Parameters: (A LOT OF OMITTED STUFF...)
```

#### Object `fields_map` (from `cache.cacheFields`)

This is a `dict` with column name and their available values:

```
{'YEAR': [2000.0, 2001.0, 2002.0, 2003.0, 2004.0, 2005.0, 2006.0, 2007.0, 2008.0,
          2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, 2012.0, 2013.0, 2014.0, 2015.0, 2016.0, 2017.0,
          2018.0, 2019.0, 2020.0],
 'FUEL': ['GASOLINE (m3)', 'AVIATION GASOLINE (m3)', 'KEROSENE (m3)'],
 'STATE': ['TEXAS', 'NEW YORK', 'MAINE', (...)],
 'REGION': ['S', 'NE', 'N', (...)]}
```

#### Object `row_dict` (before mapping)

Each row is a `dict` with column names and their values. Raw values for cache fields are not stored here. Here they are represented by their indexes in `cache.cacheFields` (see above)

```
{'YEAR': 0,  # <<<--- 0 stands for index in fields_map
 'Jan': 10719.983,
 'Feb': 12482.281,
 'FUEL': 0,  # <<<--- index in fields_map
 'Dec': 10818.094,
 'STATE': 0,  # <<<--- index in fields_map
 (...)
 'UNIT': 'm3'}
```

#### Object `row_dict` (after mapping)

After extracting raw values for cache fields from their indexes, we have a `dict` that represent all values of a row:

```
{'YEAR': 2000.0,  # extracted column value from index in fields_map
 'Jan': 10719.983,
 'Feb': 12482.281,
 'FUEL': 'GASOLINE (m3)',  # extracted from fields_map
 'Dec': 10818.094,
 'STATE': 'TEXAS',  # extracted from fields_map
 (...)
 'UNIT': 'm3'}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much! Your code works perfectly as long as there are not filters in the pivot table. It seems that in that case, the line `fields_map['field.name'] = [f.v ....]` produces an `AttributeError` on `f.v`, i.e. when the pivot table in the excel is filtered. I tried to prevent the code from crashing by adding a 'try ... except' around it ignoring the mapping for that field. The resulting dataframe keeps all the columns, but those without mapping obviously have only dummy values 1,2,3,... .

Do you have any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: After some further investigation, it seems that the reason for the `AttributeError` is not the presence of filters, but source data where some fields are blank.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [@PMHM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5910757/pmhm) excellent answer I have modified the code to take care of source data with blank cells. The piece of code that needed modification is the following:

```py
for field in pivot_table.cache.cacheFields:
    if field.sharedItems.count > 0:
        # take care of cases where f.v returns an AttributeError because the cell is empty
        # fields_map[field.name] = [f.v for f in field.sharedItems._fields]
        l = []
        for f in field.sharedItems._fields:
            try:
                l += [f.v]
            except AttributeError:
                l += [""]
        fields_map[field.name] = l
```

The complete code (mostly copy/paste from above) is therefore:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.pivot.fields import Missing

file_path = 'path/to/your/file.xlsx'

workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
worksheet = workbook['Plan1']

# Name of desired pivot table (the same name that appears within Excel)
pivot_name = 'Tabela dinâmica1'

# Extract the pivot table object from the worksheet
pivot_table = [p for p in worksheet._pivots if p.name == pivot_name][0]

# Extract a dict of all cache fields and their respective values
fields_map = {}
for field in pivot_table.cache.cacheFields:
    if field.sharedItems.count > 0:
        # take care of cases where f.v returns an AttributeError because the cell is empty
        # fields_map[field.name] = [f.v for f in field.sharedItems._fields]
        l = []
        for f in field.sharedItems._fields:
            try:
                l += [f.v]
            except AttributeError:
                l += [""]
        fields_map[field.name] = l

# Extract all rows from cache records. Each row is initially parsed as a dict
column_names = [field.name for field in pivot_table.cache.cacheFields]
rows = []
for record in pivot_table.cache.records.r:
    # If some field in the record in missing, we replace it by NaN
    record_values = [
        field.v if not isinstance(field, Missing) else np.nan for field in record._fields
    ]

    row_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(column_names, record_values)}

    # Shared fields are mapped as an Index, so we replace the field index by its value
    for key in fields_map:
        row_dict[key] = fields_map[key][row_dict[key]]

    rows.append(row_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)
```

Comment: I see you have already debugged the problem yourself :) Just to clarify: the problem arises when all cells in a field are blank, on even if only some cells are blank for a given field? Thanks for the update!

Comment: It’s enough that some cells are blank, not necessarily all.