# Double click a cell in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd, xlwings

I have a Pivoted excel sheet like below.

[image]

When I open the below Excel sheet manually and double click on any of the cells that have a number, a new sheet will be opened with the detailed data. How can I make this functionality using Python code? Basically, the Python code should automatically open the sheet in the excel file, double click on a particular cell (that will generate a separate sheet) and save as a separate excel file.

As I was not able to get any code for double clicking the cell, hence I could write the code only till reading the sheet in an excel file.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('Excelfile.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheetname']
```

Note that I would welcome the code from any library like Pandas, xlrd etc.

Comment: Pivot table is just a summary of data. Double clicking in Pivot values gives us that part of original data (on which pivot is made) that satisfies the "Row" and "Column" conditions of the pivot table. So, you can extract the same data by filtering from the original data with those row and column criteria. Just a suggestion, no idea how it could be done in python.

Comment: VBA equivalent of double clicking in a cell of values -- `Range("D6").ShowDetail = True` ... [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350855/read-generated-excel-sheet-from-pivot-table-show-details-option-using-python)

Comment: An approach to extract the pivot table's data from an Excel sheet using `openpyxl` can be found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73187540/5910757). The end result is similar as that of double-clicking a cell within the pivot table: all the underlying data can be extracted. On that answer, the output was a `pandas DataFrame`, which can be exported as an Excel file, as asked here.

Comment: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263271) was recently added on the question linked by @Naresh above, where one can use `win32com` to "Show Details" of a given cell, in a fashion very similar to the VBA equivalent also pointed also by Naresh in the comment above. Unfortunately, as far as I know, to use `win32com` you are essentially locked on Windows.